# firestore make crash in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
       at com.drriyadh.lab.ui.activity.OrdersActivity$1.onEvent(OrdersActivity.java:112)
       at com.drriyadh.lab.ui.activity.OrdersActivity$1.onEvent(OrdersActivity.java:95)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(Query.java:1133)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(:6)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(AsyncEventListener.java:42)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(:6)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8019)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Hi guys, i added "addSnapshotListener" i did not using any long in my database or anything like this and i getted this crash

my code:

```
private void getData() {
        orderColRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(XXXXX.XXXXXX);
        listenerRegistration = orderColRef.whereEqualTo("XXXXXXX", user.getUid()).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (error != null) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: " + error.getMessage());
                    Utils.showErrorMessage(getString(R.string.XXXX), activity);
                    return;
                }

                orders.clear();

                for (DocumentSnapshot ds : value) {
                    HomeOrder order = ds.toObject(HomeOrder.class);
                    order.setAccepted(ds.getBoolean("XXXXXXXX"));

                    homeOrders.add(order);
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareRecyclerView() {
        binding.rvOrders.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new OrdersAdapter(homeOrders, context);
}
```

this is everything from line 95 to 112
my firestore database did not have any long
and in the model class i just have one int

but this is crash did not show all the time
some time it gone and some time it back
but i did not did any change in this time

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers in Firestore are usually interpreted as `Long` when converting them to Java. So you should change the `Integer` you have in your `HomeOrder` class to a `Long` to ensure the Firestore mapping code can set it correctly.